# What is the current standpoint on cooking with olive oil?

Tags: cancer, oil, healthy-cooking, cooking, carcinogens

Usually I make dishes by adding a **tablespoon of olive oil** to the meat or vegetables and just have them for some time on a **teflon pan**.

I know that **frying** is done on **high temperatures** and results in lots of **carcinogens**.

But now I've read that **olive oil's burnpoint is lower** than sunflower's. Around **180 Celsius** based on the refinedness. And at that point carcinogens arise as well, and this makes olive oil more unhealthy for "warm" cooking than sunflower oil.

Does this mean that even the cooking I described above should be avoided with olive oil? Or just frying?

Comment: You can greatly improve the question if you add some reliable source that says that 1) cooking or frying with oil produces carcinogens and that 2) smoking point is important in this regard.

Comment: How does this question expand on what is already known? https://scienceornot.net/2012/09/15/is-it-safe-to-cook-with-olive-oil/

Comment: What is "warm" cooking? That's not a standard cooking term. This question needs some prior research, as Jan noted.

Comment: And if there's anything you should avoid heating to high it's that Teflon pan. You might want to lookup what Teflon does when heated past its limits.